# Counter examples for normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm looking for some counterexamples to some particular questions to do with normality in group theory.Any help would be appreciated.

Suppose H is a subgroup of a group G.

- If K is a normal subgroup of G. Show by counterexample that H ∩ K is not necessarily a normal subgroup of G
- For an arbitrary subgroup J. Show by counterexample that H ∩ J is not necessarily a normal subgroup of H.

I'm not very experienced with group theory and am not really sure what sort of groups I should be looking at here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: For the first question, you may want to try $G=S_n$, the symmetric group, and $K=A_n$, the alternating group for some value of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1:**
Let $G={\rm GL}_2(F)$ (where $F$ is any field) and let $K={\rm SL}_2(F)$, The subgroup $K$ is normal in $G$ as it is the kernel of the determinant map. Now let $H={\rm B}_2(F)$ the Borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices. Then $H\cap K$ is not normal in $G$ (nor in $K$).

**Example 2:**
Now take $G={\rm GL}_3(F)$, $H={\rm GL}_2(F)$ (seen as the subgroup of $G$ having a block $2\times2$ in the top left corner, a $1$ in the lower right corner, and $0$s elsewhere) and let $J=B_3(F)$ the upper triangular $3\times3$ matrices in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Any counterexample for your first statement is *also* a counterexample for your second statement (any normal subgroup is also a subgroup).

Take $G = D_4$, the dihedral group of order $8$ (also known as "the symmetries of the square"), let $r \in G$ be a rotation of $90^{\circ}$ (either direction), and $s$ any reflection in $D_4$(say, about the $x$-axis, for example).

Then $K = \{e,r^2,s,r^2s\}$ is a normal subgroup of $D_4$, being of index $2$.

Now $H = \{e,s\}$ is a non-normal subgroup of $G$, since $rsr^{-1} = rsr^3 = sr^{-1}r^3 = r^2 \not\in H$, and $H \cap K = H$.

(If $K$ is not required to be a *proper* subgroup of $G$, we can take $K = G = S_3$ and $H = \{e,(1\ 2)\}$).